# Image Magic Make Fails - PHP extension

Tags: php, imagemagick

So I was doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
sudo pecl install imagick
```

It all works till I get the error:

```
make: *** [imagick_class.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Which according to blog posts and forms is because of libmagick9-dev, how ever when trying to install this I get:

```
 sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libmagick9-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

E: Package 'libmagick9-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says that the package is no longer available. Try running this before executing those commands.

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
```

Also as a side note try installing packages from the repository if they are available.

Comment: I already ran those commands..... Should I run this one and then do the pecl install? There was a problem with your command: checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... configure: error: no. You need at least Imagemagick version 6.2.4 to use Imagick.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed

Comment: Yes you should run this before the `pecl` install

Comment: Well I did and I still got that error where it want's 6.2.4 - I am doing this all via ssh - is there a way to install 6.2.4 from repos?

Comment: What version does it install from the repos? Were you able to get it to work?